# Perform floodfill on UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics, flood-fill

I'm trying to perform floodfill on UIImage that has opacity. I tried implementing a 4-Way floodfill with CG(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) but reading the pixel colours and colouring pixels makes it too slow. It takes over a minute to fill a 300x100px area. I need a function like:

```
-(UIImage*)floodFillOnImage:(UIImage*)image fromPoint:(CGPoint)start;
```

that is fast enough.

Does anybody have a working implementation of or have an idea for a flood fill algorithm in Objective-C that works with UIImages? I've seen such a paint bucket tool in some iOS drawing apps.

Comment: Wonder if it's possible to write a shader that could perform this

Comment: https://github.com/chinatndave/UIImageScanlineFloodfill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it takes over a minute to flood-fill a 300×100 image, your implementation of getting and setting pixel values is probably extremely inefficient. If you draw your image into a bitmap context and then access (and modify) the pixel data directly, it should be a lot faster.

The basic approach would be to allocate a memory buffer (a C array of 4 (rgba) × width × height bytes), pass that to `CGBitmapContextCreate`, draw your source image into the context (e.g. using `CGContextDrawImage`), and then operate directly on the buffer (the pixel values). When you're done, you can create an image from your context using `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to perform floodfill on UIImage that has opacity.

Are you trying to fill the areas that are clear? If so, then there's a much simpler solution: Create a context, fill it with the desired color, draw the image on top, and then extract your completed image from the context.

If you're trying to fill the areas that are *not* clear, then there's a solution for that, too: Create a context, draw the image into it first, set the context's blend mode to [source in](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kCGBlendModeSourceIn), fill with the color, and then extract the completed image.

Comment: A flood-fill operation would imply that it finds the edges of an enclosed area of pixels that are of the same (or similar) color, e.g. a shape in a coloring book. You can't do that by simply compositing an image.

Comment: @omz: You can if the targeted “color” is transparency, or is the opposite thereof. If the questioner really is trying to flood-fill over some specific color, then yes, they will have to take a different approach, such as yours.

Comment: No, that doesn't work because a flood-fill (as the term is commonly used in imaging software) starts *at a specific point in the image*. Say you have an otherwise transparent image with an outlined circle in the middle. When you do a flood-fill that starts from the center point, the circle should be filled, but not the (also transparent) pixels around it.

Comment: See the [first image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Recursive_Flood_Fill_4_(aka).gif) in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) for an example where your approach wouldn't work.